# Add a share extension to an iOS app

Tags: ios, swift

Let me preface this by saying I'm a relatively novice programmer and have even less experience thinking about iOS. I'm looking for some information about how to access the sharing aspects of the iPhone. Unfortunately, I don't think my Google queries were using the proper terminology so let me elaborate.

I was looking at the FT website and noticed that when I clicked to share the document, there was a toolbar that popped up with the apps that are able to share. First question is if I'm trying to make an app, how do I make the app accessible on this toolbar?

[image: Sharing toolbar]

Next question. When I clicked Evernote the app seemed to automatically parse the title, put that in the text box, and also if you look to the very right of the screenshot, you can vaguely see a box which contains a link to the website. I would love to grab this information and save it to a database. Do you happen to know where I could find guidance for doing something like that?

[image: Evernote sharing]

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: By save into a database what you mean? On your own server or the device? You are taking this kind of information already? A simple way of taking this is google analytics or similar

Comment: Yeah, I just would eventually want to save it on a server. Any pointers to tutorials for how to do this would be really helpful. The edit that @AstroCB made was already super useful for my Googling.

Comment: @g.humpkins You might want to take a look at [this](http://www.imore.com/sharing-ios-8-explained) and [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionCreation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH5-SW1).

Answer (score 1):

You simply add the title, link, image, whatever you're making the user share to your share viewController, then add it as an array to the controller, it's very simple, other options you've is to exclude some of the services you don't want the user to share to, etc.

```
    let firstItem = "Share it now"
    let secondItem = generatedImageOrWhatSoEver


    let shareController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [firstItem, secondItem], applicationActivities: nil)
    self.presentViewController(shareController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

hope this's what you're looking for.